# Creating JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I achieve or create this type JSON object using PHP?

```
{
  "actors": [
    {
      "name": "Brad Pitt",
      "description": "William Bradley 'Brad' Pitt is an American actor and film producer. He has received a Golden Globe Award, a Screen Actors Guild Award, and three Academy Award nominations in acting categories",
      "dob": "December 18, 1963",
      "country": "United States",
      "height": "1.80 m",
      "spouse": "Jennifer Aniston",
      "children": "Shiloh Nouvel Jolie-Pitt, Maddox Chivan Jolie-Pitt",
      "image": "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/brad.jpg"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: you have to design an array of `PHP` and use of `json_encode` function.

Comment: @Uzuwe, Check me out.

Answer (score 0):

As i comment: you have to design an array of `PHP` and use of [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Online compile: [My answer](https://3v4l.org/lE3YP)

> Try this:

**Array**

```
$actors = array("actors" => array(
            array("name" => "Brad Pitt",
                  "description" => "William Bradley 'Brad' Pitt is an American actor and film producer. He has received a Golden Globe Award, a Screen Actors Guild Award, and three Academy Award nominations in acting categories",
                  "dob" => "December 18, 1963",
                  "country" => "United States",
                  "height" => "1.80 m",
                  "spouse" => "Jennifer Aniston",
                  "children" => "Shiloh Nouvel Jolie-Pitt, Maddox Chivan Jolie-Pitt",
                  "image" => "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/brad.jpg"
            ))
        );
```

**Encode**

```
echo $out = json_encode($actors);
```

**result:**

```
{"actors":[{"name":"Brad Pitt","description":"William Bradley 'Brad' Pitt is an American actor and film producer. He has received a Golden Globe Award, a Screen Actors Guild Award, and three Academy Award nominations in acting categories","dob":"December 18, 1963","country":"United States","height":"1.80 m","spouse":"Jennifer Aniston","children":"Shiloh Nouvel Jolie-Pitt, Maddox Chivan Jolie-Pitt","image":"http:\/\/microblogging.wingnity.com\/JSONParsingTutorial\/brad.jpg"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array containing your data and convert it to a JSON string using [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
$myData = [
    "actors" => [
        [
            "name" => "Brad Pitt",
            "description" => "William Bradley 'Brad' Pitt is an American actor and film producer. He has received a Golden Globe Award, a Screen Actors Guild Award, and three Academy Award nominations in acting categories",
            "dob" => "December 18, 1963",
            "country" => "United States",
            "height" => "1.80 m",
            "spouse" => "Jennifer Aniston",
            "children" => "Shiloh Nouvel Jolie-Pitt, Maddox Chivan Jolie-Pitt",
            "image" => "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/brad.jpg"
        ]
    ]
];

$myJSON = json_encode($myData);
```

Comment: it should start with  {"actors": [ {    NOT  "actors":  {{

Comment: i need { "actors": [ { "name": "Angelina Jolie", "description": "Angelina Jolie is an American actress, film director, screenwriter, and author. She has received an Academy Award, two Screen Actors Guild Awards, and three Golden Globe Awards.", "dob": "June 4, 1975", "country": "United States", "height": "1.69 m", "spouse": "Brad Pitt", "children": "Shiloh Nouvel Jolie-Pitt, Maddox Chivan Jolie-Pitt", "image": "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jolie.jpg" } ] }

Comment: not {"actors":{"name":"Brad Pitt","description":"William Bradley 'Brad' Pitt is an American actor and film producer. He has received a Golden Globe Award, a Screen Actors Guild Award, and three Academy Award nominations in acting categories","dob":"December 18, 1963","country":"United States","height":"1.80 m","spouse":"Jennifer Aniston","children":"Shiloh Nouvel Jolie-Pitt, Maddox Chivan Jolie-Pitt","image":"http:\/\/microblogging.wingnity.com\/JSONParsingTutorial\/brad.jpg"}}